# Best way for checking if a user is logged with node.js and express and change client-side html

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, pug

I'm doing a web application with node.js and express; I'm also using sessions with mongoDB.
My server side code is like this:

```
exports.home = function(req, res){
if(req.session.userEnabled){
    console.log("logged");
    res.render('home', { title: 'MY TITLE' , css: '/stylesheets/home.css',authenticated:'true'});
}
else{
    console.log("not logged");
    res.render('home', { title: 'MY TITLE' , css: '/stylesheets/home.css',  authenticated:'false'});
}
```

};

into my front end I check the value 'authenticated' for showing different html:

```
script.
            if(#{authenticated})
                document.write("<div id='profile' class='myClass' ><p>SHOW PROFILE<p></div>");
            else
                document.write("<div id='register' class='myClass' ><p>REGISTER<p>");
```

It works, my question is: is this a good way for giving some dinamism to the front end pages?

I tried to create a get function client side for checking if authenticated:

```
function checkIfLogged(){
$.get( '/checkIfLogged' , function(data) {
    alert('Result checkIfLogged: '+data);
    return(data);
     });
```

}

calling this into html:

```
script.
    var authenticated=checkIfLogged();
...
...
...
script.
        if(authenticated)
            document.write("<div id='profile' class='myClass' ><p>SHOW PROFILE<p></div>");
        else
            document.write("<div id='register' class='myClass' ><p>REGISTER<p>");
```

but this is asinchronous so the result returns after that the page is already loaded with a 'false' value of var authenticated.

In this way I thought I could avoid to check and to pass value from the server side into every res.render, but this doesn't work.
Is my first solution the right way or into this second way was I near to find a better way for doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
function checkIfLogged(callback){
    $.get( '/checkIfLogged' , function(data) {
        alert('Result checkIfLogged: '+data);
        callback(data);
    });
}
```

and

```
script.
    checkIfLogged(function(authenticated) {
        if(authenticated)

            //I wouldn't use document.write here as it's a bit dangerous with asynchronous call

            document.write("<div id='profile' class='myClass' ><p>SHOW PROFILE<p></div>");
        else
            document.write("<div id='register' class='myClass' ><p>REGISTER<p>");
    });
```

Comment: thanks; do you thinks it's better to put document.write into another function client side? (so I could use JQuery)